# Issues with SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have created a SQL Server trigger as below.

```
create trigger testtrigger on testdb
for insert
as
declare @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from testdb" queryout c:/test.txt -c -t -T -S localhost'

exec xp_cmdshell @sql

go
```

But when a row inserted in the testdb, the text file is created, but there is no content. Can someone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: A trigger should be very small, quick and nimble - you should **definitely NOT** call external services like the `bcp` utility from a trigger! You need to rethink your design

Comment: Also the trigger should handle multiple rows inserted in one statement (yes, possible, read up on sql syntax).

Comment: @TomTom Despite the other issues, this trigger does support multi-row inserts.

Comment: So what's the solution you recommend to export the rows to text file for each insert.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the recommendations regarding not using that approach, I'd ask you if you are sure that the insert is completed.

The most probable situation is that you're facing a deadlock, and a kind of deadlock that SQL is not able to handle because of the fact that one of the resources involved is out of SQL scope (command line).

The thing is that when you finished the insert, the trigger is activated without releasing the exclusive locks that were taken in `testtrigger`. Then the select over `testtrigger` is tried but since there still locks the select needs to wait for those locks to be released, something that will never happen because you don't close the transaction as it's waiting for the select.

So the file is created, but the insert and the select are never completed due to the deadlock.
You'll see it work by adding updating the command to:

```
'bcp "select * from inserted with(nolock)" queryout c:/test.txt -c -t -T -S localhost'
```

Of course the whole approach is not recommended but I wish it helps you understand the situation.

Comment: I will try this command. But what's the solution for exporting the row to text for each row insert.

Comment: Thanks it works with the added nolock. So whats the solution you recommend to achieve this requirement.

Comment: That depends on the purpose for doing so. If it's just for having a tracking of changes and you're using SQL 2016 or newer, you might enable temporal tables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). If you really need the export on a file, but you can run it on demand (instead of having the file generated when the table gets new rows), you could do it specifying a particular date/time and having an exact snapshot of the table at that time.

Comment: I need to export the row to text file immediately when certain condition meets. For example when some one swipes the access card on particular doors, I need that row to be exported. Don't need all the rows.

Comment: Ok, but what would be the purpose of that file, is for auditing, for somebody to read it, for another process to trigger something when the file appears?
If it's a small solution with little traffic and amount of data I would continue with that approach. But if you need something a bit more robust, scalable, etc, I would:
- Implement Service Broker
- Use AFTER INSERT trigger to send just the information inserted to a queue in the service broker
- Write the file using a CLR store procedure just with the new data inserted

Answer (score -1):

Try making the trigger AFTER INSERT and then export from the 'inserted' psuedo-table instead of the actual table 'testdb'.  The newly inserted rows will be exported.

```
create trigger testtrigger on testdb
after insert
as
if exists (select * from inserted)
    begin
        declare @sql        varchar(8000),
                @guidName   char(36)=newid();
        
        SELECT @sql = concat('bcp "select * from inserted" queryout c:/',
                             @guidName, '.txt -c -t -T -S localhost');

        exec xp_cmdshell @sql
    end
go
```

Comment: This will never work. The inserted table is not visible outside the trigger.

Comment: The query executes within the scope of the trigger.  Of course it works.  Dynamic SQL executed within a trigger can reference the psuedo tables.  I could provide you a example but you should try it yourself

Comment: It worked with no lock command. So can you please advise on the recommended solution for export the row to text file when it meets a certain condition.

Comment: @Subu, above you wrote: "...what's the solution for exporting the row to text for each row insert"  The code was switched from referencing the 'testdb' table to the 'inserted' table.  The 'inserted' table only contains the newly inserted rows so it should meet the requirement.  To further filter which rows are exported you could add a join condition or WHERE clause to the dynamic SQL.  'inserted' is called a 'virtual ( or psuedo) table' because it's not permanently allocated and it's only accessible within the scope of the trigger.

Comment: I have created a trigger to move the required rows into another table as below. use test
go
alter TRIGGER trigger2 ON testtable1
after INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO testtable2
SELECT *  FROM inserted where leaf = 'test22'
go. Now how do I export each row into a text file in a path. I am able to export the new rows to a text file as soon as they are inserted. But the text file is having all the rows which are previously inserted. I need only the new rows which are inserted and need only one row per text file.

Comment: I updated so that the file is named as @guidName a new guid when the trigger is executed